# why does "request body" have a red background in fiddler?

Tags: fiddler

Why is my local Fiddler app displaying a red background for the Composer "Request Body"?

Here's the text I'm using:  {'count':'2', 'since_id':'14927799'}

This appears to look like a standard js object to pass as parameters for a service call.

Why does Fiddler display "Request Body" with a red background when I paste in the text I'm using above.  I'm guessing Fiddler is saying that the Request Body is invalid.  If so then what am I missing here?  I'm used to calling services directly through jQuery.....

Comment: The problem was that it was a "GET" request so the params had to be appended to the querystring instead of appended to the request body

Comment: Thanks Random512 for the answer!  I was having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler's Composer will show the body background in red if it contains text but the request method is not one that carries a body (`POST`, `PUT`, etc).